# How to make my JupyterLab on a Server runs on GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am currently using a JupyterLab in a Tambora Server provided by my campus. Spec of server: https://server-if.github.io/.

I am running this code, from this https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/main/examples/flax/image-captioning using my own dataset.

Obviously, I would need a GPU/TPU to run this code, otherwise I will be spending so much time and resource to run. I've tried to utilize Tensorflow. 
[image: test GPU with TF]

Then, I try to use it so my code can run on GPU:
[image: using TF GPU]

But on the output text, this always shows (look at the bottom), even after I use TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=0:
[image: NO GPU Found]

Is there any way I can use GPU on this JupyterLab?

Also, I've tried to check this:
[image]

Comment: Looks like you need to install NVIDIA driver + CUDA correctly.

Comment: is there any references to do so? @gogasca